# protected moodledata folder (for moodle 2.2 installation) in shared 1and1 hosting

Tags: permissions, hosting, directory, moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle 2.2 on a shared linux 1and1 server. Following the web installation, I get to the step where it asks for the path of the **moodledata** folder. I've read that I need to put it somewhere without public access, which I believe means in a level above the public web root folder.

So if the public web root folder is: /homepages/44/d********/htdocs

the folder path should go be: /homepages/44/d********/moodledata

The problem is that when I want to create a folder there (connecting with ssh), I get a "permision denied" error.

I've contacted 1and1 and they're telling me that with my hosting package (dual unlimited) it's not possible to create folder in levels above the public web folder, and that I should upgrade the hosting package.

Is that the only way? Can I get a protected folder like moodle demands without having to upgrade the hosting package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what you are doing you can execute the following steps to install moodledata inside Moodle directory.

These modifications will turn off moodle verification about moodledata safety requisites.

You have to edit the file called in the root of moodle folder install.php.

Near line 230 put comments around the following code:

```
/*
    while(is_dataroot_insecure()) {
        $parrent = dirname($CFG->dataroot);
        $i++;
        if ($parrent == '/' or $parrent == '.' or preg_match('/^[a-z]:\\\?$/i', $parrent) or ($i > 100)) {
            $CFG->dataroot = ''; //can not find secure location for dataroot
            break;
        }
        $CFG->dataroot = dirname($parrent).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'moodledata';
    }
*/
```

Near line 300 put comments around the following code:

```
/*
 else if (is_dataroot_insecure()) {
        $hint_dataroot = get_string('pathsunsecuredataroot', 'install');
        $config->stage = INSTALL_PATHS;

    }
*/
```

Comment: yeah but then the moodledata directory wouldn't be secure right? I was wondering if it would be possible to keep it secure somehow.

Comment: Moodle places an .htacces file inside moodledata to prevent unauthorized access and you can always grant permissions only to the apache user inside that directory. 

I think you'll be pretty safe even with moodledata inside that directory.